Filter document based on properties in child object in CosmosDb SQL
I want to get any document with test url in ui template
Ex:
Input
    {
        "id": "id1",,
        "EntityType": "metadata",
        "UITemplates": {
            "p1": [
                {
                    "DisplayText": "UiDefinition.json",
                    "UrlString": "https://1-test",
                    "SubType": "Custom"
                },
                {
                    "DisplayText": "createuidefinition",
                    "UrlString": "https://2-prod",
                    "SubType": "Custom"
                }
            ],
            "d3": [
                {
                    "DisplayText": "UiDefinition.json",
                    "UrlString": "https://11-test",
                    "SubType": "Custom"
                },
                {
                    "DisplayText": "createuidefinition",
                    "UrlString": "https://22-test",
                    "SubType": "Custom"
                }
            ]
        }
    }

Output:
The list of id that the doc has "test" in the UrlString
[{"id", "id1"}]

The point that block me is how to get the properties from the listinguitemplates into a array, and I can use ArrayContains or self-join later to just filter it out.
Self-join but need to know the properties name under listinguitemplate beforehand
Tried to flatten but return empty
SELECT c
FROM c
JOIN p IN (
    SELECT VALUE item
    FROM item IN (
        SELECT VALUE t
        FROM t IN c.UITemplates
    )
)

If can know the fixed field of properties before
SELECT c.id, t.UrlString
FROM c
JOIN t IN c.UITemplates.p1

Result
[
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "UrlString": "https://1-test"
    },
    {
        "id": "id1",
        "UrlString": "https://2-prod"
    }
]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/join#self-join-with-a-single-item
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/array-contains
Can anyone shed some lights for me, thanks

fyi you have a data model anti-pattern, as you're using a value (like "p1" and "d3") as a key, vs having those as values of something like {"templateID": "p1", "templates": [...]}. This will make your query life more difficult.

Find that there is an sql function to map object properties into array
Since in operator only work on array, not the object properties, so need to transform properties into array first
SELECT DISTINCT c.id
FROM c
JOIN t in (SELECT VALUE ObjectToArray(c.UITemplates))
JOIN p in t.v
WHERE CONTAINS(p.UrlString, "test")

